# How to make controls like DateTimePicker to expand even if there is no space

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

My problem is that i have few controlls on page in stack layout.
And when i click DateTimePicker it is trying to fit on page and since there is no space i see only small piece of controll.
I have seen that there is no such behaviour in settings application. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you running the latest build (beta4) of the operating system? There were quite a few UI changes in this release which include fixes to the way Cascades controls expand and contract.

Comment: Also, could you post a screenshot? You can take a screenshot by pressing the up and down volume buttons together. Photos are found in the 'camera' folder.